# Why is my sed output to file different from terminal output?

Tags: bash, sed, output

Newbie here, so apologies for any missing info/silly mistakes!

I have a text file that contains a series of datasets. Each dataset comprises 6 sets of coordinates ('landmarks'), a scale and a specimen ID, like so;

```
LM=6
111 111
222 222
333 333
444 444
555 555
666 666
SCALE=0.123
ID=MS17_female_8_central_2.jpg
```

I wanted to move the first coordinate down to be the sixth coordinate, like so;

```
LM=6
222 222
333 333
444 444
555 555
666 666
111 111
SCALE=0.123
ID=MS17_female_8_central_2.jpg
```

So I tried using sed (probably clumsily). This works in the terminal;

```
sed '/LM/{n;H;d;}; /SCALE/{x;1!G;s/\n//;}' < in.txt
```

Everything looks good.
However, as soon as I try this;

```
sed '/LM/{n;H;d;}; /SCALE/{x;1!G;s/\n//;}' < in.txt > out.txt
```

The output in the created file is different. The first chunk of data looks fine, but from then onward, I have also managed to insert the 'SCALE' line from the previous chunk...

```
LM=6
222 222
333 333
444 444
555 555
666 666
111 111
SCALE=0.123
ID=MS17_female_16_central2.jpg

LM=6
222 222
333 333
444 444
555 555
666 666
SCALE=0.123
111 111
SCALE=0.124
ID=MS17_female_18_central2.jpg

LM=6
222 222
333 333
444 444
555 555
666 666
SCALE=0.124
111 111
SCALE=0.125
ID=MS17_female_19_central2.jpg
```

I can well believe that I did something stupid in my sed, but I cannot work out why the terminal and file outputs would be different.. any help much appreciated!

Comment: too many floating numbers are really not easy for others to read. please use simple data to demonstrate your problem. like `111`, `222`. see [repro] for more info.

Comment: `The output in the created file is different.` What do you use to isnpect the output? Does the output of `sed '/LM/{n;H;d;}; /SCALE/{x;1!G;s/\n//;}' < in.txt | cat -v` also looks fine?`

Comment: @pynexj apologies - will bear this in mind next time!

Comment: @KamilCuk Ooh, no - with the piped cat -v it looks more like the output file, but with an incorrect line break, e.g.

[preceding lines]
1300.13318864584 1021.87994745559^M
SCALE=0.120625275573192^M1282.36861042892 1113.66360157633^M
SCALE=0.120625275573192^M
ID=MS17_female_8_central_2.jpg^M

Comment: Your file has dos line endings. And, well, your `sed` script has a flaw.

Comment: @Laurenhsr no need to wait for next time, you can/should [edit] your question to fix your example right now this time.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk - is the flaw(s) just in using G/H rather than g/h or is there something else as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^LM/{n;h;d};/^SCALE/{x;p;x}' file
```

Match a line beginning `LM` then print it, fetch the next into the hold space and delete the fetched line.

Match a line beginnng `SCALE`, swap to the hold space, print it and swap back.

N.B. The `h` command overwrites what is already in the hold space whereas the `H` command appends to it (with a newline as a separator). Likewise the `g` command replaces the current line with the contents of the hold space and the `G` command appends the hold space to the current line (with a newline as a separator).

---

Applying a bit more thought:

```
sed '/^LM/{n;h;d};/^SCALE/{H;g}' file
```

Comment: Actually if you add semicolons after each command, then it should be POSIX sed: `sed '/^LM/{n;h;d;};/^SCALE/{x;p;x;}'`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^LM/{n;x;d};/^SCALE/{x;G}' < input_file > output_file
$ cat  output_file
LM=6
1187.62419327203 1128.4674167571
1140.25198469359 1081.09520817865
1163.93808898281 983.390027985608
1255.72174310355 971.546975840996
1300.13318864584 1021.87994745559
1282.36861042892 1113.66360157633
SCALE=0.120625275573192
ID=MS17_female_8_central_2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

> why the terminal and file outputs would be different..

You are *viewing* the output in different programs. The terminal interprets *carriage return* character as return cursor to the beginning of the line, which causes the line to be overwritten by the next line. While the other programs interprets *carriage return* character as a newline.

Your sed script `H;` *appends* to hold space, so it's only getting bigger.. You might want to `h` replace hold space.